# Composer does not index classes

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

Composer 2.0.1..

I have used version 1 and never had a problem... but now...

The problem is that classes not indexed and php fails with `"class not found in..."` error.

`dump-autoload -o` shows no errors and 1193 classes as before I have added last ones.

composer.json section

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\" : "src/"
    }
}
```

class location: `src/models/syslog.php`

class code:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Models;

class SysLog extends CustomModel {
}
```

It is a very simle task... but i have spent a lot of time and it does not work...

Read/write rights are ok.

Autoload adds this line to `autoload_psr4.php`: `'Application\\' => array($baseDir . '/src'),`

So i do not actually have a clue...

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that path in Composer2 MUST be exactly the same as namespace.

path `/src/models/syslog.php` MUST be `/src/Models/SysLog.php` for Application

I bet it is wierd but... it is true.